# How to change a string containing a dict in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

| ID | computed_data |
| --- | --- |
| 0987 | "{"Status":{"participate":14,"create":"10","activ":"0"},"rescount":22,"comcount":0,"partrate":0}" |
| 4568 | "{"Status":{"participate":49,"create":"40","activ":"27"},"rescount":22,"comcount":0,"partrate":73.47}" |
| 1234 | "{"Status":{"participate":3,"create":"3","activ":"1"},"comcount":0,"partrate":100,"rescount":42}" |

I am trying to access and get the values in the computed_data column. It works on one cell when I am using eval().

`eval(df["computed_data][0])`

I tried a for loop to change all values at once and stored every dict in a list :

```
data = []
for x, i in enumerate(df["Computed Data"]):
    data.append(eval(df["Computed Data"][x]))
```

But I got an error "name "null" is not defined". I checked and I have no null values in my df which shape is 3601.

does anyone has an idea ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution with custom function for convert not parseable strings to empty dictionaries:

```
import ast

def f(x):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x)
    except ValueError:
        return {}
        
df["Computed Data"] = df[ "Computed Data"].str.strip('"').apply(f)
```

Comment: I got the same error trying your bit of code : "malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x12bb817c0>"

Comment: @Koutaax - What is `print (df["Computed Data"].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: @Koutaax - Answer was edited, can you test?

Comment: I tried the edited answer, still the same error

Comment: I don't know what "at 0x12bb817c0" means but I guess there is a string that does not have the right pattern in my full df maybe

Comment: @Koutaax - Exactly, possible solution is convert not parseable data to empty dicts, answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) after removing the external `"` if any (your string would otherwise be an invalid input):

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['computed_data'] = df['computed_data'].str.strip('"').apply(literal_eval)
```

Output:

```
     ID                                                                                                     computed_data
0   987       {'Status': {'participate': 14, 'create': '10', 'activ': '0'}, 'rescount': 22, 'comcount': 0, 'partrate': 0}
1  4568  {'Status': {'participate': 49, 'create': '40', 'activ': '27'}, 'rescount': 22, 'comcount': 0, 'partrate': 73.47}
2  1234       {'Status': {'participate': 3, 'create': '3', 'activ': '1'}, 'comcount': 0, 'partrate': 100, 'rescount': 42}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code but I get this error : "malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x12bb817c0>"

Comment: @Koutaax can you provide an example that reproduces the error? Then what do you want to do? ignore or try to handle those errors?